# How to put a property in a different table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class:

```
@Entity
public class myClass {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
...

  private String orderIndex;
}
```

I would like to put `orderIndex` in a different table, since only few entities will have this property. I would like the tables to looks like this:

```
table myClass:
id  |  name | ...

table myClass_orderIndex:
myClass_id  |  orderIndex
```

I could not find the annotations to do this in hibernate

Comment: How about creating one-to-one relation?

Comment: @ThomasEdwin can you elaborate? how should the second class look like? will it create 2 tables or just one?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a one-to-one relation will fit your requirements. The one-to-one is guaranteed by a `@JoinColumn(unique=true)`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="myClass_orderIndex")
public class OtherClass {
   private String orderIndex;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(unique=true)
   private MyClass myClass;
   ...
}

@Entity
public class MyClass {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="myClass", cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<OtherClass> list;

  @Transient
  public String getOrderIndex() {
    if (list != null && list.size() == 1) return list.get(0).getOrderIndex();
    return null;
  } 
}
```

This will create two tables as per your requirement.